# How can I split a file?

Tags: c++, string, file, split, fstream

I was trying a code for splitting a file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int dim,k=1;
double x,y,x1,y1;
vector<double> AUX1[0],AUX2[0];
string file="ne_1417.dat",number; 
ifstream IN(file);
while(IN >> x >> y)
{
    AUX1.push_back(x);
    AUX2.push_back(y);
}
IN.close(); 
dim=AUX1.size();
number=to_string(k);
ofstream OUT(number+file);
for(int i=0;i<dim;i++)
{
    OUT<<AUX1[i]<<" "<<AUX2[i]<<endl;   
    if((AUX1[i+1]-AUX1[i])>50.){
         k++;
        number=to_string(k);
        OUT.close();        
        ofstream OUT(number+file);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I get the number of files I want but only the first file is full of data, the others are empty and I can't understand why =( 
I need help, please <3

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: What is your assignment about? Why do you implement your own `Vector` class instead of using `std::vector`? Does your `Vector` class implement bounds-checking, and what does it do when you go out of bounds (as you will do with `AUX1(i+1)`, assuming you use the function-call operator for indexing instead of the more natural index-operator `[]`)?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new on this. I use my `Vector` class just for my homework. It does not have any special stuff.

Comment: `vector<double> AUX1[0],AUX2[0];` Doesn't do what you think it does. Review vector's usage. You are declaring arrays of vectors of zero length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a matter of scoping and variable shadowing.

You have a variable named `OUT` in the function scope, defined before the writing loop. Then inside the `if` you define a *new* and totally different variable named `OUT` as well. When the scope of the block ends, so does the life-time of the new variable, and it is destructed.

You should not define a new variable, but rather re*open* the existing file:

```
if((AUX1[i+1]-AUX1[i])>50.){
     k++;
    number=to_string(k);
    OUT.close();        
    OUT.open(number+file);  // Open the new file
}
```

All of the large compilers should be able to detect the variable shadowing and issue warnings about it. If you don't get such a warning then you need to enable more warnings (I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` for GCC and Clang, and `/W4` for VC++).